# Is there Marionette `collection.remove` equivalent functionality in angular?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, backbone.js, marionette

I mean that in Marionette you can set View-Collection-Model mapping, and when you call `collection.remove(model)` Marionette find and delete model from collection, sent delete request to the server and finally update the view which displays collection items.

Does Angular has same functionality?

Or I have to find deleting element in `$scope.collection` and remove it, delete it from server and manually update the view?

Answer (score 0):

Check out angular $resource abstraction... I have another answer here on SO that explains the differences between using $http or $resource.  In the end you may end up just doing all the CRUD operations in a service and using the same data object within the controllers from the service see more here: [Angular $http vs service vs ngResource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17667455/angular-http-vs-service-vs-ngresource/17668516#17668516)

Comment: The question is not about difference between "$http and $resource".

Comment: Right I understand that my point was if you abstract everything into a service as I explain in that answer you can just re-use the data in the controller. Then if you are using $resource you can also use the convenience methods to $save or $delete an element that is returned from a query call on the $resource... that will allow you to abstract the handling of the data to a service, the data that the controller scope uses comes directly from the service so changes will be reflected in the view when the service changes the data.

Comment: Also since you didn't mention $http or $resource I figured the explanation would be helpful since you will need something to do the communicating with the server.