# Difference between AngularJS standard $http and NgResource

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-http, angularjs-ng-resource

Who can tell me at least 5 differences AngularJS standard $http and NgResource?
Expect that NgResourse is better for RESTfull Api.I searched for this but didn't find a good answer:(

Comment: Under-the-hood `ngResource` uses `$http`. Avoid `ngResource`. Instead use [restangular](https://github.com/mgonto/restangular).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular $http vs service vs ngResource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17667455/angular-http-vs-service-vs-ngresource).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [AngularJS $http and $resource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13181406/angularjs-http-and-resource)