# How to make controller function execute only once in AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a controller that is referenced in some html. And the html changes on some event so the controller function code executes multiple times.
The problem is that I have a peace of code that needs to be executed only once.
Here is the controller:

```
angular.module("someModule", [dependencies])
.controller("leftBoardController", function ($scope, someService) {
   (function createFilter(dataService) {
    // here I'm loading all the data on which I want to operate after
            // this code should execute only once
    })(TempEmployeeService);
}
```

But it executes each time the html changes.
This is how the controller is inserted:

```
<section ng-controller="TreeMapController"
                 ng-class="{ 'main-container-single': zoomed }"
                 class="minContainer main-container">
```

**Questions:**
1) How to make the controller function execute only once?
2) Or is there a way I can write this peace of code that will execute only once?

Comment: what do you mean by html changes ?? do you mean part of you page as in a section mentioned above changes or the whole page changes

Comment: I think the whole page. I change the url in my code and the html changes (the page is not reloaded)

Comment: if the page is refreshed/loaded/loaded the controller will be called again- that is what is expected

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put your "run once" code into a [service](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/services), and return a promise.

Inject that service into your controller.

For an example of a service creating and then returning a promise, and the controller then using that promise, see [Should services expose their asynchronicity?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17416599/should-services-expose-their-asynchronicity)

Comment: I did it with an array variable, it is more understandable for me